# Pull data from Excel O365 instead of Google Docs for Gooogle Visualization API

Tags: javascript, json, excel, oauth, google-visualization

I have a javascript web application that displays a timeline. (I'm using [Google Visualization API/Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) as the interface).

This timeline pulls the data from a private Google Sheet (as a json object)

I'm researching the ability to switch from using Google Sheets as my "database" to using O365 (excel online) because all my intended users have O365 as well.

Questions:

Does excel support accessing a spreadsheet as a json object or csv like google sheets does?
If I set the excel spreadsheet private and share it with some users, would I need some sort of Oauth or would it be enough for those users to simply sign in with their office accounts?

Thank you!

Comment: This may be helpful for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets

Comment: you can use the Excel REST API from Microsoft Graph to get data from a workbook in JSON format -- including data from a [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-range) or [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-list-of-table-rows)